# Explanation why $\frac{(x-1)!-(x-1)}x$ is always an integer for prime $x$

Tags: prime-numbers

> If $x$ is prime, $\frac{(x-1)!-(x-1)}x$ is always an integer.

Is there a way to explain this using modern algebra? I feel as if though it has to do with the concept of relatively prime or $\gcd$s, but I'm not exactly sure what is happening. I can verify it is true by plugging in a bunch of different primes and verifying that it works. I want to however explain this using algebra. I was thinking maybe divisor algorithm would work too. Thanks.

Comment: Look up Wilson's Theorem:
$$(p-1)! \equiv -1\;(\text{mod}\;p)$$
for all primes $p$.

Comment: @quasi This should be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take Wilson's theorem:
$$(p-1)!\equiv-1\bmod p$$
Of course, we can subtract $p$ from the LHS and the congruence will not change:
$$(p-1)!-p\equiv-1\bmod p$$
This is equivalent to
$$\frac{(p-1)!-p+1}p=\frac{(p-1)!-(p-1)}p\in\mathbb Z$$
and the claim is proved.

Comment: I see.  I get it now.  So could you just explain the pairing again in Z_5 x and how that shows the product of its elements is -1 mod p? I am starting to understand better.

Comment: @rain OK. $\mathbb Z_p^×$ is the multiplicative group associated with the (odd) prime $p$, which has $p-1$ elements. Each element in this group has an inverse element, and the product of an element and its inverse is the identity of 1. Only 1 and $-1$ are their own inverses, though. These multiply to produce $-1\bmod p$. You have a whole bunch of 1's, but only one $-1$; it follows that the product of all the elements in $\mathbb Z_p$ excluding 0 is $-1$.

Comment: Thanks! So for Z5 x only 1 is its own inverse as 1*1=1 and 1 is the identity here.  So how would this work ( I like understanding concrete cases). But wouldnt the inverse of 2 but 1/2 which is not in Z5 x?

Comment: @rain Ah! This is where most newcomers trip up. The inverse of 2 in $\mathbb Z_5^×$ _can_ be written as $\frac12$, but this is considered equivalent to 3, since $2\cdot3\equiv1\bmod5$. The only reason that guarantees an inverse for all elements in $\mathbb Z_p^×$ (and the existence of division) is the primality of $p$. Ultimately, this is the starting point for a whole sub-field of number theory: [tag:modular-arithmetic].

Comment: Got it. Thanks.