# Greatest common divisor for expression given.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Marked as Duplicate question: (Updated)
Is there an expression I can derive to get this?

I know the gcd>1 but I don't know how to get an expression for it? Or if this is not possible, how do I show the gcd>1?

Comment: See the recently asked [Explanation why $\frac{(x-1)!-(x-1)}x$ is always an integer for prime $x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2664101/explanation-why-fracx-1-x-1x-is-always-an-integer-for-prime-x).

Comment: Read that again. The $\,\gcd\,$ is in fact $\,p\,$.

Comment: @kemb Prime numbers don't have a lot of divisors. If the gcd is not $1$, what else could it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that by [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem)

$$(p-1)!+1\equiv 0 \pmod p\iff(p-1)(p-2)!+1\equiv 0 \pmod p \iff p(p-2)!-(p-2)!+1\equiv 0 \pmod p\iff (p-2)!-1\equiv p(p-2)!\equiv 0 \pmod p$$

thus since $$p|[(p-2)!-1]\implies \gcd((p-2)!-1,p)=p$$

Comment: Great,thanks, makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  use [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem) to show that $\,p \mid (p-1)! - (p-1) = (p-1)\big((p-2)!-1\big)\,$, then $\,\gcd(p,p-1)=1\,$ implies that $\,p \mid (p-2)!-1\,$ by [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma).

Comment: Wish the downvoter had left a comment why.